# useReducer just won't re-render the components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

I'm having trouble getting useReducer to re-render components. I'm doing everything immutably by making copies of everything then changing the copies. My component simply won't re-render when passed in props 'currentSection':

I am console.logging the initial state in the reducer and it's coming out as completely untouched from the changes I made.

```
  if (type === "PREFILL") {
    const newInitialQs = [...initialQuestionsState.currentSection.questions];
    const newSects = [...initialQuestionsState.questionSections];
    action.variables.forEach((variable, i) => {
      const qCopy = { ...newInitialQs[i] };
      qCopy["variable"] = variable;
      newInitialQs[i] = qCopy;
    });
    const newInitialSect = {
      ...initialQuestionsState.currentSection,
      questions: newInitialQs,
    };
    newSects[0] = newInitialSect;
    console.log("Initial Questions");
    console.log(initialQuestionsState);
    return {
      ...initialQuestionsState,
      questionSections: newSects,
      currentSection: newInitialSect,
    };
  }
```

I am using the state here which is obtained from destructuring 'currentSection' from the reducer state.

```
          <QuestionBlock
            onFinishQuestions={questionsFinishedHandler}
            questionsInit={currentSection.questions}
            dataSet={currentSection.dataSet}
          />
```

Logging currentSection.questions outside the component shows the updated state but inside it shows the initial state. In the reducer function I am returning a brand new currentSection object.

```
    return {
      ...initialQuestionsState,
      questionSections: newSects,
      currentSection: { ...newInitialSect, questions: "bingo" },
    };
```

I tried returning the above from the reducer where I make sure the currentSection is a brand new object with a completely new questions property.... still  won't re-render.

In the  component I am using the props to set state:

```
const QuestionBlock = ({ onFinishQuestions, questionsInit, dataSet }) => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([...questionsInit]);
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
  const [dataSetName] = useState(dataSet);
  const [lineItems, setLineItems] = useState(
    questionsInit[questionsInit.length - 2].looping && [
      ...questionsInit[questionsInit.length - 1].variable,
    ]
  );
  const [looping] = useState(questionsInit[questionsInit.length - 2].looping);
```

The only way I can make the component re-render is by using Math.random() as the key but this doesn't seem ideal. Would be nice to understand why the state change isn't re-rendering it.

Using useEffect to log if the state has changed seems to indicate that it is in fact changing.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currentSection);
    console.log("STATE UPDATED");
  }, [currentSection]);
```

Comment: Show where `currentSection` is coming from in the component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.